# how to ignore the first index in required field validation

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am doing required field validation checking, first of all i hard coded "Select an item" to my `ddllocation`, but when i clicks submit button, system doesn't prompt me a required field message. am I missing out something?

**Code Behind**

```
  ddlLocation.DataSource = dsResult.Tables[0];
  ddlLocation.DataTextField = "location_nm";
  ddlLocation.DataValueField = "location_id";
  ddlLocation.DataBind();
  ddlLocation.Items.Insert(0, "----Select an Item----");
```

**HTML**

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvLocation" runat="server" 
ControlToValidate="ddlLocation"Display="Dynamic" CssClass="ErrorMsg"
ErrorMessage="Mandatory" InitialValue="1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should set the  `InitialValue` by:

```
InitialValue = "----Select an Item----"
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
 ddlLocation.Items.Insert(0, "----Select an Item----");
```

to

```
ddlLocation.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("----Select an Item----", "1"));
```

because you have given initial value of `RequiredFieldValidator` as 1

You can give initial value which will not in the data you bind to drop down list

If you insert item without creating list item, the value field of that item will be null value. then you can't give value to initial value field of the `RequiredFieldValidator`

Answer (score 0):

FIrst you should insert item in list by this way

```
ddlLocation.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("-select item-","0" ));
```

Then you can set inital value in `RequiredFieldValidator`  like this

```
InitialValue = "0"
```

0 is preferred because may be 1 can be id of any other location in `dropdown` .